# A word, expression or idiom to describe a problem that is not obvious but can potentially be very destructive

Tags: expressions, idioms

I am looking for a word, expression or idiom to describe a problem that is not obvious but can potentially be very destructive.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I suggest you take a look at the expectations surrounding [Single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). As it stands, you're not specific enough about the use of the word/expression/idiom, and you don't provide a sample sentence or context in which it will be used. Answerers benefit from those items.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ‘insidious’: *proceeding in a gradual, subtle way, but with very harmful effects*. (The definition is from the Oxford English Dictionary.)

Comment: that is a good one! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would use ***SNAG***:

''a concealed or unexpected difficulty or obstacle''
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snag)

Or:

''informal

a problem, difficulty, or disadvantage:

We don't anticipate any snags in/with the negotiations.''

(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snag?q=Snag+)